# How to release video player in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i want to know how to release video Player in flutter i am new to flutter help me.

I want to stop last played video inside PageView whenever user scroll to new Page then stop previous page Video or release previous Page controller.

Below is my Code.

```
class _VideoPlayerItemState extends State<VideoPlayerItem> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin,TickerProviderStateMixin{


VideoPlayerController _videoController;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: _videoController != null ? _videoController.value.initialized
                      ? AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _videoController.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: VideoPlayer(_videoController),
                  )
                      : Container() : Center(child: Text("LOADING VIDEO ON NULL"),),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
      ],
  );
}
```

This code execute when user scroll Pageview.

```
onPageChangedForTutorial(PageController pageController) {
setState(() {
  _videoController  = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoUrl)
    ..initialize().then((value) {
      _videoController.play();
    });
  _videoController.setLooping(true);
});



 }

}
```

Facing the Error : whenever i will scrolled the page previous video not stop until the new video initialize. I want to stop instant whenever i will scrolled to new page Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setState(() {
  _videoController.pause();
  _videoController.dispose();
  _videoController  = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoUrl)
    ..initialize().then((value) {
      _videoController.play();
    });
  _videoController.setLooping(true);
});
```

Comment: you want to stop the video when this method gets call onPageChangedForTutorial

Comment: yes i want to stop previous played video onPageChangedForTutorial method